# Proxying streaming file upload in Spring to S3

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-s3, spring-boot, binaryfiles

I have the requirement of streaming a file through a service to S3. This is a **non-multipart** put of a file to my service. **I will not know the file size ahead of time.** I can use the low-level [S3 API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpListPartsJavaAPI.html) to perform the transfer to S3.

I have a Vert.x Proof-of-Concept that streams the file, uploading each chunk as it's received in my service with no spooling to disk. I would like to create a similar POC in Spring Boot but all I can find are examples that return the whole file to my controller instead of calling it with each chunk that is transferred over the wire. As I may be receiving large file the cost of spooling to disk or storing the whole file in memory is too high. Is there anyway to achieve this functionality using Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Found out you can use [SeverletInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletInputStream.html) to accept a stream and then proxy that request onward to S3.